# Angular 2+: Error POST http://localhost:3000/api/pups/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: angular, http, post, service, routes

**I am trying to post a JSON object to web service.**
This is what I get when I execute my code:
[image]

This is my code :

**Component.ts**

```
createPup() {
const newPup = {
  name: this.name,
  age: this.age,
  breed: this.breed
};

this.__pupService.createPup(newPup).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
    return true;
  },
  error => {
    console.error('Error Adding Pup!');
    console.log(newPup);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }
);
this.router.navigate(['/pups']);
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
createPup(newPup) {

const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
const body = JSON.stringify(newPup.data);

return this.http
  .post(this._url, body, options)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json()
  );
}
```

Comment: You should check the logs server side

Comment: Just as a note, stack overlfow recomends not linking images with useful data in them in case image links die. It may be a good idea to write out the text in the image aswel so that this question will be helpful in the future.

Comment: Everything seems fine -_-"

Comment: I don't think you have to stringify the body content, just provide the object itself. `this.http
  .post(this._url, newPup.data, options)` or even without the data call like `this.http
  .post(this._url, newPup, options)`

Comment: Thnx for your help guys I solved the problem! The error was caused by a wrong database query.